# Android O notification not showing

Tags: android, notifications, android-8.0-oreo

I'm trying to implement notifications for Android O version.
I've read about notification manager and channels. So Android O still doesn't want to reproduce notifications. On main Activity in PostCreate method I wrote this.

```
    NotificationManager mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";
    String CHANNEL_NAME = "my Channel Name";
    int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, NOTIFICATION_ID,
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    NotificationChannel notificationChannel = null;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

        notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
                CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        notificationChannel.setShowBadge(true);
        notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);

        mNotifyManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }
    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    Notification myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .setContentTitle("You have been notify")
            .setContentText("This is your Notifiaction Text")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_donut_large_black_24dp)
            .setChannel(CHANNEL_ID)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .build();

    mNotifyManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, myNotification);
    Toast.makeText(this, "accepted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

After build for 26th API it doesn't create Notification, Toast message fires, and logs say me:

> W/Notification: Use of stream types is deprecated for operations other than volume control
>   W/Notification: See the documentation of setSound() for what to use instead with android.media.AudioAttributes to qualify your playback use case

How to handle this case of error?

Upd. After some investigating, I've found that 26 api uses a little changes in notification builder. Now it accepts chanelid too. So for 26 use builder with two parameters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notification not showing up in Android O despite creating a channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46255675/notification-not-showing-up-in-android-o-despite-creating-a-channel)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass channel id while creating notification/notificationcompact object.

```
Notification.Builder(Context context, String channelId)
```

or

```
NotificationCompat.Builder(Context context, String channelId)
```

Comment: I do it, but Toast message fires, and logs continue say me: "W/Notification: Use of stream types is deprecated for operations other than volume control W/Notification: See the documentation of setSound() for what to use instead with android.media.AudioAttributes to qualify your playback use case"

Answer (score 2):

You should not use the setSound method on the notifcation builder but instead use your created notification channel to set those settings.

```
notificationChannel.setSound(Uri sound, AudioAttributes audioAttributes);
```

Comment: I tried doing that, but still the default sound comes when a notification arrives. Any suggestions what might be missing

Answer (score 2):

I get the warning too but I noticed that I'm still actually getting the notification(pulled down the tray), just that it was silent and not displaying the icon in the system bar...

I see that your importance is set to low: `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW` for a channel (mine was too), which wouldn't play the sound, you need to set it to `IMPORTANCE_HIGH` or `IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT` to actually see and hear your notification.

Answer (score -3):

Your alarmSound should probably be something else, not a URI?

Comment: Issue is in new Android O notification. It doesn't appear even without setSound, and warning in logs stay the same.